# Target users of Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been developing on Visual Studio, and here comes Visual Studio Code which is described as a source code editor that supports multiple platforms. For me, I find it promising considering it's a lightweight editor compared to Visual Studio.

Since Visual Studio Code is still a baby, is it safe to say as time passes by and this baby becomes mature, this will be the new Visual Studio considering it can run on multiple platform?

Does Visual Studio Code has a roadmap on the upcoming features?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code will not replace the regular Visual Studio, if that's what you're asking. VSCode is intended to be a very lightweight, code-focused IDE. There are a plethora of features present in Visual Studio that I don't expect we'll ever see in VSCode simply because they are not within the scope of the project. For example, I don't think you'll ever see the designer in VSCode, which is something you would sorely miss if you were developing a WPF or WinForms application.

Right now VSCode seems to be mostly targeting web application developers using ASP.NET 5 and node.js.

As for what's ahead for VSCode, I'm not sure if a roadmap has been laid out anywhere but I do know that a plugin/extension system is in the works, along with ES6/7 support and a few other things.

If you want to follow the development of VSCode, check out their [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vscode/), [Twitter](https://twitter.com/code), and [UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/).

Comment: yep, you can read more about what it is here ... http://johnpapa.net/visual-studio-code